# R write a rows of a data frame as a text string

Tags: r

I am using R to prepare a data file that is then read by an external Fortran program. The Fortran program expects a specific format whereby the 1st line of the file is a file description, the second line is the integer of n variables to be expected in the file, the next n lines are the variable names, and finally the lines of data with the variable values separated by one space.  As an example consider a simple data frame with some X, Y, Z coordinates.  The following R script does what I want using loops but is quite slow for a data frame with tens of thousands of rows and tens of columns.

```
# dummy data frame
tmpA <- c(1000,2000,300)
tmpB <- c(1010,2010,305)
df <- data.frame(rbind(tmpA,tmpB))
names(df) <- c("X", "Y", "Z") 
# numbers of rows and columns 
ncol <- length(names(df))
nrow <- length(df$X)

# make the header first two lines
tmpA <- "Coordinate data"
tmpB <- ncol
tmpA <- rbind(tmpA, tmpB)

# append the filed names to the first two header lines
for (i in 1:ncol) {
  tmpA <- rbind(tmpA, names(df)[i])
}

# append the data lines as a space delimted string
for (i in 1:nrow) {  
    tmpB <- ""
    for (j in 1:ncol){   
      tmpB <- paste(tmpB, df[i, j])
      tmpB <-trimws(tmpB)
    }
  tmpA <- rbind(tmpA,tmpB)  
}

# Write the data file
write.table(tmpA, "data.dat", row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
```

Now, this is a very Fortran way of dealing with the problem. I'm looking for a faster R-way of doing this that avoids all the looping?

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```r
foo <- c("Coordinate data", ncol, names(df), apply(df, 1, paste, collapse = " "))
writeLines(foo, "data.dat")

readLines("data.dat")
#> [1] "Coordinate data" "3"               "X"               "Y"              
#> [5] "Z"               "1000 2000 300"   "1010 2010 305"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cat` to write to a file. With `do.call(paste, df)` the values of *df* are paste together separated by one space.

```
cat("Coordinate data", ncol(df), names(df), do.call(paste, df), sep = "\n", file="data.dat")

readLines("data.dat")
#[1] "Coordinate data" "3"               "X"               "Y"              
#[5] "Z"               "1000 2000 300"   "1010 2010 305"
```